# Wordpress Multisite Subdomains not displaying images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Ok so the problem I am getting is images on a subdomain on the new MU install i made do not show up, The images on the main domain are showing.

Post show up fine on the subdomains.

here is a link to an article with an broken image. http://books.faithfortheheart.com/face-to-face/

my .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

my config file has this

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'faithfortheheart.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

been searching for solutions for several days can't seem to find whats up. I did also check and make sure the files were uploading. the images are uploading, but the URL is leading to a 404, so rewrite issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was my permission for the subdomains upload directories were being set to 750 instead of 755, making it impossible for any public access.